# Resize text when mouse enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have next fiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u2k1y5w/1/) where I want to resize text instead of image

Bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 header" ><img src="http://www.mandroid.in/demo/srems/images/news_image_01.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 header" ><img src="http://www.mandroid.in/demo/srems/images/news_image_01.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 header" ><img src="http://www.mandroid.in/demo/srems/images/news_image_01.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 header" ><img src="http://www.mandroid.in/demo/srems/images/news_image_01.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row text">
<div class="col-md-4 ">text</div>
<div class="col-md-4 ">text</div>
<div class="col-md-4 ">text</div>
<div class="col-md-4 ">text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
height:1000px;
width:100%;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

#header_div {
width:100%;
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".header img").mouseleave(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "50px"
       }, 600);
   });

   $(".header img").mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "100px"
       }, 600);
   });

   $(".text div").mouseleave(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "50px"
       }, 600);
   });

   $(".text div").mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           height: "100px"
       }, 600);
   });
 })
```

So as image, I can change size of image, but text don´t get bigger. Any help is very appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use `fontSize` to change the size of the text. So replace `height` with `fontSize` Modify your `".text div"` events like this.

```
$(".text div").mouseleave(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           fontSize: "50px"
       }, 600);
   });

   $(".text div").mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).stop().animate({
           fontSize: "100px"
       }, 600);
   });
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LfLaz31m/).

Comment: and there are no way to get bigger but into div? so text can´t get out from it?

Comment: what do you mean ? can you explain little bit more ?